# State Machine Will Not Accept Input Path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I'm sure someone will point me to an immediate solution, but I've been at this for hours, so I'm just going to ask.

I cannot get a State Machine to accept an initial input. The intent is to set up an EventBridge trigger pointed at the State Machine with a static JSON passed to the SM to initiate with the proper parameters. In development, I'm just using Step Functions option to pass a JSON as the initial input when you select "New Execution".

This is the input:

```
{"event":{
  "country": "countryA",
  "landing_bucket": "aws-glue-countryA-inputs",
  "landing_key": "countryA-Bucket/prefix/filename.csv",
  "forecast_bucket": "aws-forecast-countryA",
  "forecast_key": "inputs/",
  "date_start": "2018-01-01",
  "validation": "False",
  "validation_size": 90
} 
}
```

When looking at what is passed at the ExecutionStarted log entry:

```
{
  "input": {
  "country": "countryA",
  "landing_bucket": "aws-glue-countryA-inputs",
  "landing_key": "countryA-Bucket/prefix/filename.csv",
  "forecast_bucket": "aws-forecast-countryA",
  "forecast_key": "inputs/",
  "date_start": "2018-01-01",
  "validation": "False",
  "validation_size": 90
} 
,
  "inputDetails": {
    "truncated": false
  },
  "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::a-valid-service-role"
}
```

This is the State Machine:

```
  "Comment": "A pipeline!",
  "StartAt": "Invoke Preprocessor",
  "States": {
    "Invoke Preprocessor": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "InputPath": "$.input",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:my-lambda-arn:$LATEST"
      },
      "Next": "EndSM"
    },
    "EndSM": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "Ended",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried nearly anything I can think of from changing the InputPath to assigning the "input" dictionary directly to a variable:
`"$.event":"$.input"`
To drilling down to the individual variables and assigning those directly like:
`"$.country:"$.country"`. I've also used the new Step Functions Data Flow Simulator and can't get anywhere. If anyone has any thoughts, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edited for correct solution:

You need to set the `Payload.$` parameter to `$`. That will pass in the entire `input` object to the lambda.

```json
{
  "Comment": "A pipeline!",
  "StartAt": "Invoke Preprocessor",
  "States": {
    "Invoke Preprocessor": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:my-lambda-arn:$LATEST",
        "Payload.$": "$"
      },
      "Next": "EndSM"
    },
    "EndSM": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "Ended",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this, the issue seems to be maybe on the Lambda side? No matter what input path I designate, the Lambda says that the key is not present in the input. 

Right now I'm passing the whole input path with "$", which is a dictionary and should go to the Lambda as the "event". Then I access the individual variables by using eg event["country"]. I also tried assigning directly to the variable eg $.country=$.input.country. But regardless I get a "Key Error"...

Comment: I would l look at the Step Input in the step functions console, or just log the event in the lambda. That way you can see exactly what it being passed into your function. If you look at the step input it will be the part inside the Payload.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do is specify the input in the parameters, this will allow you to specify only all/certain parts of the json to pass in.

```
{
  "Comment": "A pipeline!",
  "StartAt": "Invoke Preprocessor",
  "States": {
    "Invoke Preprocessor": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "InputPath": "$",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:my-lambda-arn:$LATEST",
        "input_event.$": "$.event"
      },
      "Next": "EndSM"
    },
    "EndSM": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "Ended",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

From the code perspective you could just reference it like so (python):
`input = event['input_event']`